# VisualStudio | summary with keyword 'null'

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, resharper, summary

I have a `property` which can be `null`. I want to documentate this in the `summary` and here is my problem.

#### cref

```
/// <summary>
/// Can be <see cref="null"/>.
/// </summary>
public object FooProperty;
```

`ReSharper` says, there is a `Syntax Error`, but the highlighting is working as expected!

[image: Syntax Error]
[image: highlight]

#### cref nested

```
/// <summary>
/// Can be <see><cref>null</cref></see>.
/// </summary>
public object FooProperty;
```

[image: not working]

When formating it to `nested`, the highligghting is **not** working anymore.

#### langword

```
/// <summary>
/// Can be <see langword="null"/>.
/// </summary>
public object FooProperty;
```

`langword` is working, but there is no `intelliSense` in `VisualStudio`.

Can someone please tell me what is the right way to documentate these `keywords` and `IntelliSense` support would be nice!

#### solution approach

- [VisualStudio | CodeSnippet for inside comment/summary block (IntelliSense)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47712650/6229375)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **langword** is the way to go. You are right, there's no Intellisense support for this. It's probably because it's not [officially recommended XML comment tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments) attribute. But the tools that can generate documentation from your comments, e.g. Sandcastle Help File Builder or VSdocman (disclaimer, I'm the developer of VSdocman) will recognize this syntax and will generate a special text. For example, VSdocman generates:

null reference (**Nothing** in Visual Basic)

The same applies to [other reserved words](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/aseelinkxml.htm), such as true, abstract, etc.

While Intellisense will not help you, VSdocman has a WYSIWYG comment editor which can assist you with more complex comments.

One more note to `<see cref="null"/>`. This will create a link to the class,  method or property named **null**. This is not directly possible in C#, where you need to prepend @ before the name that is a reserved word:

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="@null"/>
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
    public void @null() {}
}
```

But this is perfectly valid in VB .NET:

```
''' <summary>
''' <see cref="null"/>
''' </summary>
Public Class MyClass
    ReadOnly Property null As String
End Class
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you! Do you know if it is possible to add a new snippet I could use in the 'summary' area?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 (v17.4.4), there is IntelliSense support for the `<see langword="null"`/> construct. It even shows a dropdown of the possible values of the langword attribute.

[image]